# Slim Framework shows blank page on redirect

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to use Slim Framework's redirect, however it isn't working at all. Here is an example:

```
// Viewing a note
$app->get('/n/:id(/:password)', function ($id, $password = null) use ($app, $tl, $settings){
    // User has requested a note
    $note = $tl->load($id);
    // Check if note is valid
    if ($note) {
        // No problems, note is valid
        $app->render('note.php', ['note' => $note, 'settings' => $settings, 'password' => $password]);
    } else {
        // Note has been deleted or doesn't exist, render error
        $app->flash('error', '<p>The requested note doesn\'t exist. It may have expired or been deleted.</p>');
        $app->redirect('/');
    }
});

// Get posted password
$app->post('/n/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
    // Hash password, redirect user back to note
    $app->redirect('/n/' . $id . '/' . SHA1($app->request->post('password')));
});
```

When I submit the form on the previous page, it posts to /n/:id, but then simply displays a blank page. The same goes for the homepage redirect in the ifelse statement. If I open the Chrome developer tools, I can see that the status of the request is 200, and the method is POST. Adding an error_log to the request handler shows me that the request is made, but the redirect does nothing. I've enabled all error reporting, but nothing is shown.

It was working literally hours ago, so I have no idea what's wrong with it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a link to your complete file?

Comment: I'm not really happy to share the entire project publicly as it's part of a larger commercial solution, however if someone has a thought on what the problem might be then I'm happy to share it over email - benedict@ovalbit.com

Comment: Did you register the redirect route?

     $app->get('/n/:id/:sha' ....

Comment: See edit for redirect route.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you commented out all of the code within $app->get('/n/:id(/:password)' route, to check if the implementation of the route is causing this problem

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference.

Comment: You say that the status is 200 and the method is post, but thats the post request. The second request you make is redirect, so it should be a 302 status (default) and with a get method. Could you please try to preserve the log in chrome. Network -> check 'Preserve log' option and see if it's really redirecting.

Comment: There is no second request, that's the problem. The redirect call literally does nothing at all.

Comment: Hmm, maybe a long shot but could you dump the headers.

var_dump(headers_list());

Maybe somehow the status header is already set and is wrong. In that case you could try to set the status manually 

$app->response->setStatus(302);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58373/discussion-between-benedict-lewis-and-cocheese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised what it was, and now hate myself. I was including a library with require before my redirect, and that library had a blank space before `<?php`, so an empty line was being sent. This meant that the headers were already set so the redirect didn't work.